# INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER with Facebook SDK when I build multiple productFlavors

Tags: android, facebook, android-contentprovider, android-facebook, android-productflavors

I'm building an Android app with multiple `productFlavors`, and using Facebook SDK v4.1 for login and sharing contents. The problem is that when I try to install an app on a device which already has the same app installed (but different flavor), it raises an error. It doesn't allow me to install the second app unless I uninstall the existing one.

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{my_app_id}"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

According to this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth), the `android:authorities` should be unique and I should have multiple auths to accomplish what I want to do. However, I can't have multiple Facebook AppIds, and was wondering if there's better way to solve this problem. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me!

Comment: `android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{my_app_id}"` needs to be unique. It seems that another app having same authorities. Read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271246/install-failed-conflicting-provider-in-android

Comment: @PankajKumar Please read my question carefully.

Comment: do u have any workaround for this problem now?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295117/set-a-global-variable-in-gradle-that-can-use-in-manifest-file

Answer (score 7):

Try below : 
 Manifest

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider${facebookId}"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="fb${facebookId}"/>
```

Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.package"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        manifestPlaceholders = [facebookId:"123456789"]
    }

    productFlavors {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        manifestPlaceholders = [facebookId:"1234"]
    }
    release {
        applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        manifestPlaceholders = [facebookId:"123456789"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, one question, why you need "fb" before fb${facebookId} ?

Comment: what a trick! without 'fb' before ${facebookId} app crash with "invalid app id' message, I think it is converted to number, and add prefix 'fb' can prevent this?

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException [See Android Facebook source code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/1cafb982455f10fa4b7cc5e5374627a3efff49d7/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java#L758)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

Manifest

```
<provider android:authorities="@string/facebook_app_authority"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Gradle

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.id.flavor1"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_authority", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider0000000000000000"
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.id.flavor2"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_authority", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider0000000000000001"
    }
}
```

Replace 0000000000000000 to your App id

Answer (score -7):

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{app id here}"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: How is this different to the existing provider definition?

Comment: Copy pasted same code what is the difference in code for question and solution