# Set a global variable in gradle that can use in manifest file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to create a global variable similar with applicationId. 
It is set value in build.gradle and will be used in manifest. Is it possible?

Comment: gradle is a part of build system/ IDE, not related with the app

Comment: if you explain the real use case, I think may be we can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set them, for instance I'm setting it for different product flavors

```
productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId = "com.myapp.app"
            resValue "string", "authority", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider5435651423234"
        }
        development {
            applicationId = "com.myapp.development"
            resValue "string", "authority", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider2134564533421"
        }
        qa {
            applicationId = "com.myapp.qa"
            resValue "string", "authority", "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider29831237981287319"
        }
}
```

And use it like this

```
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="@string/authority"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: Thank so much. This is exactly my situation. I've tried to set a variable facebookProdiderId inside build.gradle then reused inside android manifest  file like ${facebookProdiderId}, but it does not work

Comment: Glad I could help you! :)

Comment: can we use same applicationId with multiple flavors in this.

Comment: @TusharPandey to be honest not sure, I think it could work, give it a try.

Comment: I got solution , there is no need of  content provider. it only requires when we pick image from gallery and share it in facebook.

Answer (score 19):

If you just want to use the application id set in gradle in your manifest, you can simply use:

> ${applicationId}

For instance:

```
<provider
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.ShareFileProvider" ... >
    ...
</provider>
```

If you want the same behavior with custom variables, you can use manifestPlaceholders, like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
    }
}
```

And in your manifest:

```
<intent-filter ... >
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="${hostName}" ... />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html for more information.

Answer (score 17):

While Marko's answer seems to work, there's currently a better solution that doesn't require adding variables to the string resource files.

The [manifest merger accepts placeholders](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger):

> For custom placeholders replacements, use the following DSL to
>   configure the placeholders values :

```
 android {
     defaultConfig {
         manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"defaultName"]
     }
     productFlavors {
         free {
         }
         pro {
             manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"proName" ]
         }
     }
```

> will substitute the placeholder in the following declaration :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="${activityLabel}" >
```

You can also manipulate those strings with groovy functions.

Comment: This is a more convenient solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To use the string in `Manifest`, you can directly make it in `strings.xml`.
Like this,

```
<string name="variable_name">value</string>
```