# How to handle "Package couldn't be installed" error

Tags: android

> Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.bconV2-pguDOQBwYd1UAj1JeJHhxA==: Can't install because provider name com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider290493298246611 (in package com.bconV2) is already used by com.bcon
>
> Session 'app': Error Installing APKs

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Hello and welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_CONFLICTING\_PROVIDER with Facebook SDK when I build multiple productFlavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723802/install-failed-conflicting-provider-with-facebook-sdk-when-i-build-multiple-prod)