# Android application with different package name but same code did not installing on one device

Tags: android, package, conflict

I am working on an android application. Meanwhile i got chance to work on another application similar to first. I have just copy my previous code to new
project.

1) src files

2) res files

3) manifest

4) build.gradle

and then I change packagename from com.abc to com.xyz in

1) build.gradle

2) Manifest

3) src files

Now i have installed first app in my device and try to install second one but it does not work. 
Same error also occur when i have installed second app and try to install first one.

Here is the error

[image]

Is there any other thing i need to change apart from packagename??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be different issues, but try this:
go to gradle and change `applicationId`, another reason could be conflicting of authorithies in apps, refer to these:

[Install shows error in console: INSTALL FAILED CONFLICTING PROVIDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267785/install-shows-error-in-console-install-failed-conflicting-provider)

[INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271246/install-failed-conflicting-provider-in-android)

http://gradlewhy.ghost.io/overcoming-install-failed-conflicting-provider/

Comment: do you have contentProvider in these apps?

Comment: Not my own but use facebook content provider for logged in.

Comment: issue solved just comment facebook content provider code

Comment: @user2121089 could you past string which you removed ? I think we can solve that without removing. I faced with the same issue but with MAPS_RECEIVE permissions in two same applications on one device

Comment: I didn't remove anything, conflict comes from same authority, third link is pretty useful, I advice you to read it fully.

Comment: In Manifest 
 <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider170559530034548"
            android:exported="true"/>

change FacebookContentProvider170559530034548 replace app id with new app id

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in the same case and I solved it by adding `applicationId`. In my case problem was in permission.MAPS_RECEIVE, I saw that in error logs. So I did next:

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: Yes i did it by
 <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvide‌​r170559530034548" android:exported="true"/> change FacebookContentProvider170559530034548 replace app id with new app id